# robots.txt remove entire subdomain/directory

Tags: robots.txt

I have a subdomain forums.example.com

It is in public_html/forums

If I put the following robots.txt in public_html/forums will it remove all the forums from the index? (I migrated forums to a different provider and want to remove all the forum pages from google's index)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 2):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /forums/
```

If you don't put the folder name "forums" you will be completely removed from google/spider robots for all your content in that web host.